# Label and text box moving to the right when excuting program in Python tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I am starting to learn Python with the Cambridge University Press, Python by Example. I have started with tkinter GUI and I am not sure if the results I am getting are expected.

For instance first program is to get a user to enter their name in a text box and print out "Hello + Name" in a second text box while turning the bg colour of the second text box yellow and text blue.

label is set to column=0, row=0 and text box for user entry is set to column=1, row=0. The second text box is set to column=0, row-1 and only appears once a button is clicked.

When the program starts the items are in the positions expected, however once the button is clicked the label and entry box appear to move to the center of the screen and not sure why this is and if this is how things should be but I doubt it is.

If someone could tell me how to fix this it would be much appreciated.

The code is as follows

```
# Create a window that will ask the user to enter their name. When they click on
# a button it should display the message “Hello” and their name and change the
# background colour and font colour of the message box

# import required modules
import tkinter as tk

# Function definitions
def click():
    # Assign user input to variable "name"
    name = str(entry1.get())
    # Assign the word "Hello" and the users name to variable "message"
    message = str("Hello "+ name)
    # Create text box to display Message
    message_display = tk.Text(master=window, height=2, width=30)
    # On button click turn box background yellow
    message_display["bg"] = "yellow"
    # On button click turn text displayed blue
    message_display["fg"] = "blue"
    # Position output box on screen
    message_display.grid(column=0, row=1)
    # Assign value of variable "message" to outputbox
    message_display.insert(tk.END, message)

# Create main window
window = tk.Tk()
# Add title to window
window.title("My First Window")
# Set initial window size
window.geometry("400x400")

# Lable definitions

# Create label which display "Enter your name:"
label1 = tk.Label(text = "Enter Name: ")
# Position label on screen
label1.grid(column=0, row=0)

# Input entry

# Create entry box
entry1 = tk.Entry()
# Position entry box on screen
entry1.grid(column=1, row=0)

# Buttons

# Create button with "Click Me"
button1 = tk.Button(text= "Click Here", command=click)
# Position button on screen
button1.grid(column=0, row=1)

# Call main program loopa
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You know that you are creating a `tk.Text` widget over the button without removing the button, right?

Comment: @TheLizzard Cheers, I had just noticed that and corrected it. Both my button.grid and message_display grid were set the same. Noob mistake :) I also figured out why eveything on row one appeard to move to the right on execution. It was becuase I set the display_message width to 30, which was much more than required. I have now set it to 15 and all appears more normal.

Comment: So did that fix all of your problem?

Comment: @ TheLizzard Your comment highlighted an issue I did not spot and did not realise existed :) Thanks for that. Modifying the width of the output text box and using "sticky = "W" on the label and input box solved my initial issue of everything appearing to shift to the right on row 0 when button was clicked. So, now I know what the issue was and what to watch for going forward.